# How to fix "Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [100, 50]" error?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

I am getting this error but do not know how to solve it.I want to have two x variables for my regression, so I put them together in the code. However I am nw getting this error, and do not know how to reshape my array to solve this.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score,mean_squared_error

X = maindf[['Graduate Degree','Asian American Population']].values.reshape(-1,1)
Y = maindf["Democrats 2016"].values.reshape(-1,1)
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test, = train_test_split(X, Y,train_size=49, random_state=np.random)
DecisionTreeRegModel = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=3).fit(x_train, y_train)
y_pred = DecisionTreeRegModel.predict(x_test)
from sklearn import tree
```

Here's the error.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-85-9aaccff5b23d> in <module>
      5 X = maindf[['Graduate Degree','Asian American Population']].values.reshape(-1,1)
      6 Y = maindf["Democrats 2016"].values.reshape(-1,1)
----> 7 x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test, = train_test_split(X, Y,train_size=49, random_state=np.random)
      8 DecisionTreeRegModel = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=3).fit(x_train, y_train)
      9 y_pred = DecisionTreeRegModel.predict(x_test)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py in train_test_split(*arrays, **options)
   2125         raise TypeError("Invalid parameters passed: %s" % str(options))
   2126 
-> 2127     arrays = indexable(*arrays)
   2128 
   2129     n_samples = _num_samples(arrays[0])

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in indexable(*iterables)
    291     """
    292     result = [_make_indexable(X) for X in iterables]
--> 293     check_consistent_length(*result)
    294     return result
    295 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_consistent_length(*arrays)
    254     uniques = np.unique(lengths)
    255     if len(uniques) > 1:
--> 256         raise ValueError("Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of"
    257                          " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
    258 

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [100, 50]
```

Comment: Have you checked `X.shape` and `y.shape` to see why `train_test_split` sees one input with 100 rows and the other with only 50 rows?

Comment: Aside: `.to_numpy()` is recommended over `.values`. See [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to reshape your predictors, doing that will flatten your matrix, so instead of:

```
X = maindf[['Graduate Degree','Asian American Population']].values.reshape(-1,1)
```

Do:

```
X = maindf[['Graduate Degree','Asian American Population']]
```

Below is running your code with an example dataset:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score,mean_squared_error

maindf = pd.DataFrame({'Graduate Degree':np.random.choice([0,1],100),
                      'Asian American Population':np.random.choice([0,1],100),
                      "Democrats 2016":np.random.choice([0,1],100)})

X = maindf[['Graduate Degree','Asian American Population']]
Y = maindf["Democrats 2016"].values.reshape(-1,1)
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test, = train_test_split(X, Y,train_size=49, random_state=np.random)
DecisionTreeRegModel = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=3).fit(x_train, y_train)
y_pred = DecisionTreeRegModel.predict(x_test)
```